# Failing to expand extensions on only one account

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Trying to run just a basic https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=extensions
But either get this error

> Expected ',' instead of '{'

with

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity"{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "The entity instance value of type 'microsoft.graph.user' doesn't have a value for property 'id'. To compute an entity's metadata, its key and concurrency-token property values must be provided.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "39759fbe-06ed-4176-8cc3-efe167a532cb",
      "date": "2017-05-17T22:47:35"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to find the id of my openExtensions my account so I can delete some to make room because I must of accidentally added too many but I can't even get a list of the extensions and I can't even filter it by id. All works fine with other accounts I think i must have just bricked my account while playing around with it. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Trying the query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,displayName&$expand=extensions

results in

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(id,displayName,extensions)/$entity","id":"MY ID","displayName":"MY NAME","extensions@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('MY ID')/extensions","extensions":[{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension"{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Unsupported extension property type.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "9fe3c7aa-f3d8-48be-90e4-b440516f9010",
      "date": "2017-05-17T23:14:46"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try the query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,displayName&$expand=extensions ? I think you have to $select the user id field.  I also recommend you try the open extension samples in the [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#). Click the 'show more samples' link and then check Extensions.

Comment: Tried that and put the response as an edit above. At this point I've tried nearly every possible way of querying it i think. Is there anyway to just clean my extensions? Thanks for your quick response though :)

Comment: Thanks for reporting this.  We'll take a look at the issue and get back to you.

Comment: No worries, is there any front end where you can see openExtension data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one of our devs took a look at the data and it looks like you were calling the API incorrectly - which was valid JSON, but not what our service can handle - especially on read back.
It looks like when you were creating an open extension, you were pushing the following in the payload:

`{ "openTypeExtension": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.Extensibility.openTypeExtension",
    "extensionName": "roaming.settings",
    "randvalue": 1
  } }`

But the `openTypeExtension` bit is not required and throws us off on a read back.  What you should be sending is:

`{
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.Extensibility.openTypeExtension",
    "extensionName": "roaming.settings",
    "randvalue": 1
}`

We've implemented a fix to prevent this in the future, which will roll out next week.

We have the IDs for your extensions, so you could delete them, but we're not sure how to communicate these to you securely.  If you are OK with us providing them on this thread, please let us know.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Yea, not surprised I was calling in incorrectly, I know what I am doing now so hopefully shouldn't do anything like that again. But glad my hopelessness may help someone else making the same mistake. If it's not too much trouble could you please post the ID's in a private note https://privnote.com/ Not sure how sensitive they could be. Thanks Heaps!

Comment: https://privnote.com/iuCzRDew#5hyBxndSz - hopefully you'll get to read this before someone else does.

Answer (score 1):

I think I just ran into a similar problem.

I created my extension like this

```
var ext = new OpenTypeExtension();
ext.ExtensionName = "[Unique Name]";
ext.AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
ext.AdditionalData.Add("[settingName]", "[settingValue]");
await graph.Me.Extensions.Request().AddAsync(ext);
```

But now I can no longer expand the extensions property for my account.

```
var profile = await graph.Me
    .Request()
    .Expand("extensions")
    .GetAsync();
```

This throws a `Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException`:

`Code: generalException
Message: Unexpected exception returned from the service.`

When I try to make the request in the graph explorer, I get the following response,

```
{
    "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity"
    {
        "error": {
            "code": "BadRequest",
            "message": "The entity instance value of type 'microsoft.graph.user' doesn't have a value for property 'id'. To compute an entity's metadata, its key and concurrency-token property values must be provided.",
            "innerError": {
                "request-id": "5e3887db-1687-461a-8d5c-da0f34eea83b",
                "date": "2018-06-01T01:41:12"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I use Graph API lib.
Finally I was able to retrieve the extension other way - using **Users.Extensions** property (I guess it can be done against current user analogically - **Me.Extensions**).

I added the extension this way:

```cs
    var additionalData = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "DataName", value } };

    await graph.Users["userId"]
               .Extensions
               .Request()                
               .AddAsync(new OpenTypeExtension { ExtensionName = "uniqueExtensionName",  AdditionalData = additionalData });
```

..and retrieving:

```cs
    var extensionObject = ( await graph.Users["userId"].Extensions.Request().GetAsync() )
                                .CurrentPage[0];
```